# Ant: fileset "dir" attribute with a runtime expanded full path

Tags: java, ant

Let's say I have a file-system that looks a little something like this:

- C:\stuff\build.xml
- C:\stuff\myfolder\library1.jar
- C:\stuff\myfolder\library2.jar

Inside build.xml, I want to define a path that looks like this:

```
<path id="some.id">
    <fileset dir="myfolder">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

Normally that works fine.  However, I am calling my own custom Ant Task that will inherit any references (including the path "some.id") and that custom Ant Task will call a build.xml that lives in a different basedir.  Therefore, the "dir" attribute in the fileset is no longer valid.

Is there a way to define a "dir" such that it remains valid no matter where the second build.xml lives?

I essentially want to do something like this:

```
<fileset dir="${expand.current.directory}/myfolder">
```

So when I call the second build.xml it will understand that the "dir" attribute is the location of:

```
<fileset dir="c:\stuff\myfolder">
```

**Edit:** Furthermore, I want a solution that allows me to copy the "stuff" project from one machine to another without requiring a change to the build.  For example, if the "stuff" project is on the C: drive and I copy the project over to a D: drive on another machine, I want the build to continue to work without me having to go into the build and change the letter C to the letter D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're after the `${user.dir}` property - which is the current working directory.

All java [System.properties](http://www.mindspring.com/~mgrand/java-system-properties.htm) are available as ant properties.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**
You can define an Ant property.

At the beggining of the file you can define this property:

```
<property name="myproject.root.path" location="C:/stuff/"/>
```

And then, use it:

```
<fileset dir="${myproject.root.path}/myfolder">
```

**Option 2:**
You can also define it at an external build.properties file, located at the same folder in wich the build.xml file is.

File C:\stuff\build.properties

```
myproject.root.path=C:/stuff/
```

And, to make use of this file you have to add this line at the Ant XML file (recommended before the tasks definition):

```
<property file="build.properties"/>
```

Once you have this file included, you can use the properties along the project, the same way as seen at option 1:

```
<fileset dir="${myproject.root.path}/myfolder">
```

You can add more than one properties file.

Note that paths are defined using slashes, and not back-slashes.

Comment: Sorry I probably should have clarified in my question that I would like to make sure the solution is actually machine independent.  If I were to copy the "stuff" project onto a machine that has a D: drive, then the above solution wouldn't work without updating the ant/properties file.  Apologies for forgetting to add that in my original post.

Comment: That's a good reason to extract it to a properties file, where you could change the environment dependent values without the need to rewrite your build.xml file.

Comment: Other option could be what's told by martin clayton at the other answer, access the java runtime properties (as ${user.dir} ).